# OpenCV: Use imshow on mac

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I want to show an image with OpenCV in and Python on a mac:

cv2.imshow('image', img)

However, I get:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/aaa/PycharmProjects/untitled/aaa.py
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvShowImage, file /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 583
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/AAAA/PycharmProjects/untitled/aaa.py", line 32, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.error: /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:583: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvShowImage
```

However, what can I do on a mac? apt-get doesnt work of course...

Comment: How did you install OpenCV exactly?

Comment: I used `brew tap homebrew/science & brew install opencv3 --with-contrib --with-python3`. However, it basically works (imread, blur, threshold, ....) only the display does not...

Comment: Not sure, but maybe try `--with-qt` as well.

Comment: hm, this doesn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: You did re-compile after adding Qt? Please show your code and compile command to help debug.

Comment: @Pascal Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @Okky unfortunately not, so far :/ Do you have the same problem?

Comment: @Pascal had the same problem, solved it by reinstalling opencv with python 3.5

Issue was python 3.6 is not compatible for opencv